# Windows 7 network connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2003

On our company's network of 3 windows 2003 servers and 2 dozen or so XP machines, we have had to add 3 windows7 machines. The network is setup as a workgroup, not a domain. After a couple of weeks of everything being fine, now one of the Windows 7 machines cannot connect to 1 of the servers.

Connections to the other machines in the workgroup are working. Trying to connect to the server, we get a dialog asking for network user and password. Nothing we put in those boxes allows it to connect. I setup a new user on the Windows 7 machine, thinking something might be corrupt. No go. It has me totally stumped. I am looking for any suggestions at all to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Must be plenty of work to mange that as workgroup. Good chance there are passowrd issues with no DC

Comment: Glad you got your issue solved, @carlcroom! Could you repost your edit as a separate answer, and then click the "accepted checkmark" icon? That's how we mark questions as solved on this site.

Comment: I've posted the solution as a separate answer. Do feel free to post the solution as your own answer and mark it as accepted, I will delete my answer

Answer (score 1):

> Problem Solved thanks to ComputerGuy55
>
> This is an issue involving Windows 7
>   computer trying to connect to an older
>   server (2000/2003) Open regedit
>
> Go TO
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA
>
> Create DWORD LmCompatibilityLevel edit
>   value to 1
>
> Restart computer and all should be
>   good

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the CAL on the server?

Check through the event logs on the server to see if there are any error messages when you try to connect with the Win7 machine.

Also do the same on the Win7 machine itself to see if there are any errors at the client end.